# SQL only select the rows which has a max of 1 duplicate

Tags: mysql

I'm playing with some SQL, and trying to figure out how to select rows with a max of 1 duplicate.

Suppose I have a table looking like this:

```
CODE:
1234567
1234567
1234567
4567890
4567890
2414351
```

Then I only want to show those rows with a max of 1 duplicate, so the result should show:

```
CODE:
4567890
4567890
2414351
```

Have tried to play with max and count functions but can't seem to produce the right result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want codes which either appear only once, or have at most one duplicate:

```
SELECT t1.CODE
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CODE
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY CODE
    HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2
) t2
    ON t1.CODE = t2.CODE
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

### Rextester

Comment: The join is totally unnecessary. The subquery alone is absolutley sufficient. Would have gotten it right, if I read your question more thorough.

Comment: @fancyPants No, the join is very necessary, because the OP wants to get back all original records.  Your query, in addition to having had a wrong `HAVING` clause, also does not return all original records.  Read the question.

Comment: I can't see anything in the question, that suggests that there are more columns and the desire to list those is nowhere expressed in my eyes.

Comment: @fancyPants Um...look at the expected output, which _clearly_ shows code `4567890` appearing twice.

Comment: @fancyPants Believe me, I know the feeling all too well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group by` and `having`

```
select code from table Group by code having Count(*)=2
```